# How do I apply function to just the class a jquery ajax submission was done from?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(){
        $('.post_container').append('test <br />');
    }
});
<% sleep 1 %>
```

It is similar to the code I used for my single main micropost form but with this there are several comments that use the same class and so test is being applied to all post_containers rather than the one the post was just made to. "test" text will eventually be replaced with the div that holds the actual comments users post.

Normally I would use "this" but that won't work here.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="post_content">
    <div class="post_container">
        <div class="userNameFontStyle">
            <%= link_to current_users_username.capitalize, current_users_username %> -
            <div class="post_time">
                <%= time_ago_in_words(m.created_at) %> ago.
            </div>
        </div>  
        <%=  simple_format h(m.content) %>
    </div>
    <% if m.comments.any? %>
    <% comments(m.id).each do |comment| %>
    <div class="comment_container">
        <%= link_to image_tag(default_photo_for_commenter(comment), :class => "commenter_photo"), commenter(comment.user_id).username %>
        <div class="commenter_content">
            <div class="userNameFontStyle">
                <%= link_to commenter(comment.user_id).username.capitalize, commenter(comment.user_id).username %> - <%=  simple_format h(comment.content) %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="comment_post_time">
            <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago.
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <% if logged_in? %>
    <%= form_for @comment, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :micropost_id, :value => m.id %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, :placeholder => 'Post a comment...', :class => "comment_box", :rows => 0, :columns => 0 %>
    <div class="commentButtons">         
        <%= f.submit 'Post it', :class => "commentButton" %>
        <div class="cancelButton">
            Cancel
        </div>
    </div>   
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I deal with this?

Kind regards

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to happen? Did you code not work? You aren't specifying a URL to actually make the call.

Comment: Is it something like `$('.post_container').submit(...)`

Comment: I want to simply append the new comment to the comments list. I'm using ruby on rails framework and most of the ajax is set up by just adding "remote => true" to my form. With the code above if the ajax post was submitted successfully then I want to append the comment on to the comments list. The code above appends to all .post_container classes on the page rather than just the one I posted a new comment from.

Comment: Does `.post_container` fire the submit event ?

Comment: May be you can post your `html` code sample here, that will help us.

Comment: I will.. but I doubt it'll help

Comment: How is the binding, is it something like `$('.post_container').submit(...)` ?

Comment: Nope.. If you look at my html the button that is actually clicked is "#commentButton" and that fires the XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Can you give us the code surrounding the ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I had to do it in the end.

.new_comment is my form id

```
$('.new_comment').on('ajax:success', function(){
    $(this).parent('.post_content').find('.comment_container:last').after("<BR />TEST <BR />");

});

<% sleep 1 %>
```

The only issue now is identifying the actual comment_container for the post just made.

Answer (score 0):

NEW:

```
$(function() {
    $('.post-form').submit(function(){
        var $post_content = $(this).find('.post_content');

        $.ajax({
            url: this.attributes['action'],
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function() {
                $post_content.append('test <br />');
            }
        })
        return false; //this will stop the form from really submitting.
    });
});
```

This should do what you're looking for. Simply include this javascript anywhere.

OLD:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: this.attributes['action'],
        data: $(this).serialize(),

        //the below line might need to be adapted.
        var post_content = $(this).find('.post_content');

        success: function() {
            $(post_content).append('test <br />');
        }
    })
```

this assumes that there is only one form on the page. However, for the code to completely work, I need to know how to differentiate which .post_content is the "submitted" post_content. How do you programatically determine that? Is there a different button for each post_content? Or are there different forms around each post_content div? Whichever way it is, you'll have to include that somehow into the js code.

Comment: There is 1 form but it's part of an "each" loop so for every micropost with comments a form is displayed underneath.

Comment: Then this should work, shouldn't it (with the one addition I added)? simply include this js file, and every time a form with class "post-form" is submitted, then the ajax request will run instead. Does this work for you?

Comment: Um, I don't think you can declare your post_content variable there. You're doing it in the middle of the options object that you're passing to the ajax() function. Declare it before you start your ajax function.